# Video upload and stream (All type of file video,image,doc etc upload and display using Laravel VueJs)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I have successfully upload video but unable to stream video from Laravel storage/app folder.

***My Vue Js Code***

```
 <video width="120" height="240" controls>
   <source :src="videoFullPath" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The videoFullPath state value is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/candidate_video/7/6514082.mp4`.

Comment: I'll suggest you check if the video loads via http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/candidate_video/7/6514082.mp4, maybe on a new browser tab. And also don't forget to close the source tag . </source>

Comment: not work plz help me

Answer (score 0):

If someone face same problem plz follow below step

***Step 1 : Create below method in Controller for file upload,display***

```
     function manageUploads($file, $savepath, $gid = ""){
        if ($gid == "" || $gid == null || $gid == 0) {
            $maxGroupid = UploadFileGroups::max('file_group_id');
            $file_group_id = $maxGroupid + 1;
        } else {
            $file_group_id = $gid;
        }
        $savepathgid = $savepath . '/' . $file_group_id;
        $original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
//        $size = $file->getClientSize();
        $name = rand(1111111, 9999999) . '.' . $extension;
        Storage::putFileAs($savepathgid, $file, $name);
        $uploadData['filename'] = $name;
        $uploadData['original_filename'] = $original_filename;
        $uploadData['filebasepath'] = $savepath;
        $uploadData['filepath'] = $savepathgid;
        $uploadData['upload_type'] = $extension;
        $uploadData['upload_size'] = '0';
        if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension == "jpeg" || $extension == "png" || $extension == "gif" || $extension == "JPG" || $extension == "JPEG" || $extension == "PNG" || $extension == "GIF") {
            $uploadData['meme_type'] = "image";
        }
        else if($extension == "mp4" || $extension == "webm" ){
            $uploadData['meme_type'] = "video";
        }
        else {
            $uploadData['meme_type'] = "doc";
        }
        $upload = UploadFiles::create($uploadData);
        if($upload){
            if ($gid == "" || $gid == null) {
                $maxGroupid = UploadFileGroups::max('file_group_id');
                $gid = $maxGroupid + 1;
                $uploadgroupData['file_group_id'] = $gid;
                $uploadgroupData['file_id'] = $upload->id;
                $uploadgroups = UploadFileGroups::create($uploadgroupData);
            }
            else{
                $uploadgroupData['file_group_id'] = $file_group_id;
                $uploadgroupData['file_id'] = $upload->id;
                $uploadgroups = UploadFileGroups::create($uploadgroupData);
            }
        }
        if($uploadgroups){
            return $uploadgroups->file_group_id;
        }

    }
    function displayFile($file_id){
        $upload = UploadFiles::where('id', $file_id)->first(); 
        if (!$upload) {
            return response("Null Media File", 403);
        }

        $filePath = $upload->filepath . "/" . $upload->filename;

        if (!Storage::exists($filePath)) {
            if ($upload->meme_type == 'doc') {
                return abort(404);
            }
            else {
                return response('File Not Found', 403);
            }
        }

        if ($upload->upload_type == "jpg") {
            $type = 'image/jpeg';
        } else if ($upload->upload_type == "gif") {
            $type = 'image/gif';
        } else if ($upload->upload_type == "png") {
            $type = 'image/png';
        } else if ($upload->upload_type == "PNG") {
            $type = 'image/png';
        } else if ($upload->upload_type == "pdf") {
            $type = 'application/pdf';
        } else if ($upload->upload_type == "doc") {
            $type = 'application/msword';
        } else if ($upload->upload_type == "docx") {
            $type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        } else if ($upload->upload_type == "ppt") {
            $type = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
        } else if ($upload->upload_type == "pptx") {
            $type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
        } else if ($upload->upload_type == "mp4") {
            $type = "video/mp4";
        } else if ($upload->upload_type == "webm") {
            $type = "video/webm";
        } else {
            $type = 'image/jpeg';
        }

        header('Content-Type:' . $type);
        return readfile(Storage::path($filePath));
    }
    function getFile($groupId) {
        return UploadFileGroups::where('upload_file_groups.file_group_id', $groupId)
            ->leftJoin('upload_file', 'upload_file.id', 'upload_file_groups.file_id')
            ->select('upload_file.*')
            ->orderBy('id','desc')
            ->first();
    }

    function getImageFile($groupId){
        return $data = UploadFileGroups::where('upload_file_groups.file_group_id', $groupId)
            ->join('upload_file', 'upload_file.id', 'upload_file_groups.file_id')
            ->select('upload_file.*')
            ->where('upload_file.meme_type','image')
            ->orderBy('upload_file.id', 'desc')
            ->first();
    }

    function getAllFiles($groupId) {
        return $data = UploadFileGroups::where('upload_file_groups.file_group_id', $groupId)
            ->join('upload_file', 'upload_file.id', 'upload_file_groups.file_id')
            ->select('upload_file.*')
            ->orderBy('upload_file.id', 'desc')
            ->get();
    }

    public function deleteFile($id) {
        $file = UploadFiles::where('id', $id)->first();
        if($file){
            $filelocation = $file->filepath;
            $filename = $file->filename;
            $filePath = $filelocation . '/' . $filename;
            $filepathfull = Storage::path($filePath);
            if (Storage::exists($filePath)) {
                unlink($filepathfull);
                UploadFileGroups::where('file_id', $id)->delete();
                UploadFiles::where('id', $id)->delete();
                return 'Deleted Successfully';
            }
        }
        else{
            return 'File Doesnot Exists';
        }
    }
```

***Step 2 Create this function in app.js***

```
methods: {
            getMedia: function (id) {
                return window.location.origin + "/api/displayFile/" + id;
            },
            
        },
```

***Step 3 Now use html video tag***

```
                            <video width="1220" height="240" controls>
                            <source :src="$root.getMedia(videoUploadFile.id)" 
                             type="video/mp4">
                            Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
```

***Step 4 :To Play video u have to fetch file using user_video value***

```
$candidate->user_video_file = $this->getFile($candidate->user_video);
```

***Step 5 , In vue js part assign video file to videoUploadFile state***

```
            axios.get("/getCandidate").then((response) => {

                if(response.data.candidate){
                    this.videoUploadFile = candidate.user_video_file;
                }});
```

***--------Note create user_video column integer type-----***

***Step 6 ,Now upload file and save into database as a integer value using manage upload function which is declare in step 1***

```
                                                 <input
                                                    ref="file"
                                                    type="file"
                                                    @change="
                                                        handleFile('image')
                                                    "
                                                    name="user_image"
                                                    accept="image/*"
                                                    id="cover-upload"
                                                />
```

```
        handleFile(type) {
            if (type == "image") {
                this.form.userImage = this.$refs.file.files[0];
            } else {
                this.form.cv = this.$refs.cv.files[0];
            }

            axios.post("/addCandidateProfileImage", form).then((response) => {
                if (type == 0) {
                    location.reload();
                }
                this.getCandidate();
            });
        },

        addImage(id, type) {
            var form = new FormData();
            form.append("userImage", this.form.userImage);
            form.append("userCV", this.form.cv);
            form.append("id", id);
            axios.post("/addCandidateProfileImage", form).then((response) => {
                if (type == 0) {
                    location.reload();
                }
                this.getCandidate();
            });
        },
```

```
 public function addCandidateProfileImage(Request $request)
    {
        if (isset($request->id)) {
            $user = Candidate::find($request->id);
        } else {
            $user = new Candidate();
        }
        if ($image = $request->file('userImage')) {
            $groupId = $user->user_image == 0 ? '' : $user->user_image;
            $uploadGroupId = $this->manageUploads($image, $savepath = 'candidate', $groupId);
            $user->user_image = $uploadGroupId;
        }

        if ($image = $request->file('userCV')) {
            $groupId = $user->cv_id == 0 ? '' : $user->cv_id;
            $uploadGroupId = $this->manageUploads($image, $savepath = 'candidate_cv', $groupId);
            $user->cv_id = $uploadGroupId;
        }
        if ($video = $request->file('userVideo')) {
            $candidate = Candidate::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->with('user')->first();
            if ($candidate) {
                $groupId = $candidate->user_video == 0 ? '' : $candidate->user_video;
                $uploadGroupId = $this->manageUploads($video, $savepath = 'candidate_video', $groupId);
                $candidate->user_video = $uploadGroupId;
                $candidate->save();
                return response()->json(compact('candidate'));
            }
        }
        $user->save();
        return response()->json(compact('user'));
    }
```

Comment: that is complete code of upload and display all type of file

Comment: Can you upload multiple images/file or even a single image or video just like Instagram using this?